# How do I insert a space before a number in a string if it matches a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to insert a space before a number in a string if my string has a capital letter, one or more lower case letters, and then a number right after it.  That is, if I have

```
Bdefg23
```

I want to insert a space between the "g" and the "23" making the above string

```
Bdefg 23
```

So this string would not get changed

```
BabcdD55
```

because there is a capital letter before "55".  I tried this below

```
str.split(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/).delete_if(&:empty?).join(' ')
```

but it works too well.  That is, if my string is

```
Ptannex..
```

it will turn it into

```
Ptannex ..
```

How can I adjust what I have to make it work for only the condition I outlined?  Btw, I'm using Ruby 2.4.

Comment: I don't know the Ruby syntax, but use a regular expression that matches a capital letter, 1 or more lowercase letters, then a digit. Put the letters in a capture group and the number in a capture group, then replace them with the 2 back-references separated by a space.

Comment: Try [`s.sub(/\A([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[a-z])(\d+)\z/, '\1 \2')`](https://ideone.com/XNwnRY) or [`s.sub(/\A(\p{Lu}\p{L}*\p{Ll})(\d+)\z/, '\1 \2')`](https://ideone.com/JLyfnB)

Comment: Hi @Wiktor, You're solution (I tried the second one) worked for me.

Comment: @Natalia I posted an answer with explanation.

Comment: @Natalia If my answer proved helpful to you, please also consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
s.sub(/\A(\p{Lu}\p{L}*\p{Ll})(\d+)\z/, '\1 \2')
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/JLyfnB).

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `(\p{Lu}\p{L}*\p{Ll})` - Group 1:

  - `\p{Lu}` - any Unicode uppercase letter
  - `\p{L}*` - any 0+ Unicode letters
  - `\p{Ll}` - any lowercase Unicode letter
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\z` - end of string.

The `\1 \2` replacement pattern replaces the whole match with the contents of Group 1, then a space, and then the contents of Group 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do it roughly this way:

```
%w[
  Bdefg23
  Ptannex95
  BigX901
  littleX902
  CS101
  xx900
].each do |example|
  puts '%s -> %s' % [
    example,
    example.sub(/\A([A-Z][a-z]+)(\d+)\z/, '\1 \2')
  ]
end
```

Which gives you output like:

```
Bdefg23 -> Bdefg 23
Ptannex95 -> Ptannex 95
BigX901 -> BigX901
littleX902 -> littleX902
CS101 -> CS101
xx900 -> xx900
```